# Salesforce click2dial not working on contacts list

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

i have setup a CallCenter within salesforce. The callcenter is configured with a CTI  Softphone.

If i log in with the Softphone, is see the click2dial action on a contact-detail as expected (Image 1).[image: Image 1]

However, on the contact-list page, it  displays "Softphone is disabled" (Image 2)[image]

How can i enable click 2 dial for the contacts list?

Thank you in adavance

Answer (score 0):

Nope, its an idea. There may be workarounds with custom code

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVeOUAV/click-to-dial-from-list-view-and-related-list-view